# Let $f\colon X \to Y$ be homeomorphic and $A \subset X$. Show that $f_1\colon A \to f[A]$ is also homeomorphic.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $f\colon X \to Y$ be homeomorphic and $A \subset X$. Show that $f_1\colon A \to f[A]$ is also homeomorphic.

First we need to show that $f_1$ is continuous. Take $O \subset f[A]$ open. Now since $f[A]$ has the subspace topology we have that $O = f[A] \cap O’$ for some $O’$ open in $Y$. Now $$f_1^{-1}[O] = f_1^{-1} [f[A] \cap O’] = f_1^{-1} [f[A]] \cap f_1^{-1} [O’] = A \cap f^{-1}[O’] \cap A = A \cap f^{-1}[O’] $$ that is open in $A$ since $f$ is continuous.

Now we need to show that $f_1$ is an open map. Take $U \subset A$ open. Now from the subspace topology we have that $U = A\cap U’$, where $U’ \subset X$ is open. Thus $$f_1[U] = f_1[A \cap U’] = f_1[A] \cap f_1[U’] = f[A] \cap f[U’]\cap f[A] = f[A] \cap f[U’]$$ that is open  in $f[A]$ since $f$ is open.

I think I should still prove that $f_1$ is bijective, but I don’t know how to start this? Any hints would be apprecited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is injective, then $f_1$ is injective too. And if $b\in f(A)$, then there is some $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b(\iff f_1(a)=b)$. Therefore, $f_1$ is surjective too.

Comment: $f_1$ is surjective just by it’s construction since the codomain is the image right? However I’m not sure how the proof goes that it’s injective just because $f$ is?

Comment: @Wondera If $f_1(x)=f_1(y)$ then $f(x)=f_1(x)=f_1(y)=f(y)$ and since $f$ is injective we must have $x=y$.

Comment: Concerning your first question, the answer is affirmative. And, whenever $x,y\in X$ are such that $f(x)=f(y)$, we have $x=y$. In particular, this is true if $x,y\in A$. That is, $f_1$ is injective.